# How to make a scroll bar for buttons?

Tags: python, tkinter, interface

I want to make a scroll bar in the left panel but i dont know how. The error is due to i cant make a scroll for a frame, but in that frame i want to create buttons and scroll them.
I want to do a panel like that:

[image]

Thats waht I tried

```
import tkinter as tk

# crear ventana
aplicacion = tk.Tk()

# info de la pantalla
width= aplicacion.winfo_screenwidth()
height= aplicacion.winfo_screenheight()

# tamaño de la ventana
aplicacion.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
aplicacion.title("Gestor de Flotas - Tallers Citoler")

# titulo de ventana
aplicacion.title("Tallers Citoler - Gestor de flotas")

# color de fondo de la ventana, de momento no pongo ninguno
aplicacion.config(bg='gainsboro')

# panel superior(etiqueta titulo)
panel_superior = tk.Frame(aplicacion, bd=1, relief = tk.FLAT, bg = 'steelblue')
panel_superior.pack(side=tk.TOP)

# etiqueta titulo
etiqueta_titulo = tk.Label(panel_superior, text='Tallers Citoler - Sistema de Gestion de Flotas', fg='black',
                        font=('Dosis', 58), bg= 'darksalmon' , width=43)
etiqueta_titulo.grid(row=0, column=0)

# panel izquierdo
panel_izquierdo = tk.Frame(aplicacion, bd=1, relief=tk.FLAT, bg = 'steelblue')
panel_izquierdo.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

fondo_panel_izquierdo = etiqueta_titulo = tk.Label(panel_izquierdo, bg= 'lightgrey', width=100, height=65)
fondo_panel_izquierdo.grid(row=0, column=0)

# panel derecho (left panel)

panel_derecho = tk.Frame(aplicacion, bd=1, relief=tk.FLAT, bg = 'steelblue')
panel_derecho.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

fondo_panel_derecho = panel_derecho = tk.Label(panel_derecho, bg= 'khaki', width=172, height=65)
fondo_panel_derecho.grid(row=0, column=0)


# scrollbar panel izquierdo (left scroll bar)
scrollbar_panel_izquierdo = tk.Scrollbar(panel_izquierdo)
scrollbar_panel_izquierdo.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')

# attach scrollbar to panel_izquierdo (left panel)
scrollbar_panel_izquierdo.config(command=panel_izquierdo.yview)
scrollbar_panel_izquierdo.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_panel_izquierdo.set)


aplicacion.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a scrollbar to a group of widgets in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-group-of-widgets-in-tkinter)